# Thumbnails in the django admin panel using sorl

Tags: django, django-admin, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to have the pictures I upload in the Django admin panel to show up as thumbnails instead of the path. I have sorl installed and can make thumbnails that show up in my views.

I have found 2 snippets (http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/579/ and http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/934/) that I have tried to implement, but both attempts have failed because of the meager documentation and my as yet shallow understanding of the Django framework.

Could someone please provide a dumbed-down step-by-step guide of how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah :) I can ;)

First you need to create a custom template tag that handles the thumbnail:

```
from django.template import Library
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_headers

register = Library()

def results(cl):
    out = []
    for item in cl.result_list:
        url = cl.url_for_result(item)
        code = '<a href="%(url)s">%(img)s</a> <div><a href="%(url)s">%(title)s</a></div>' % {
            'url': url,
            'img': item.preview.thumbnail_tag,
            'title': item.title,
        }
        out.append(mark_safe(code))

    return out

def gallery_result_list(cl):    
    return {'cl': cl,
            'result_headers': list(result_headers(cl)),
            'results': results(cl)}
result_list = register.inclusion_tag("admin/app_name/model/change_list_results.html")(gallery_result_list)
```

where item.preview.thumbnail_tag is the thumnail created by sorl :)
[I got the original code from the default template tag]

Second you need to create a template for your model (that uses the new custom template tag), it must be in this directory schema:
templates_dir/admin/app_name/model/change_list.html

and have the following code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load adminmedia admin_list my_admin_tags i18n %}

{% block result_list %}
    {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
    {% gallery_result_list cl %}
    {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

as you can see in the tag function you need to create one more template (called change_list_result.html) for display the image correctly:

```
<style>
td.page { text-align: center; }
td.page a { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
{% if results %}
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
{% for result in results %}
    <td class="page">
        {{ result }}
    </td>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
</tr><tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

so at the end you'll have 3 files:

1. templates_dir/admin/app_name/model_name/change_list.html
2. templates_dir/admin/app_name/model_name/change_list_result.html
3. your_project/app_name/templatetags/my_admin_tags.py

and, of course, templatetags must be added to INSTALLED_APP in settings ;)

this is all ;) Hope this can be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old post, but I think I may have found a shorter way than the admin template override method above (though that is a pretty awesome solution - I'll have to use it in another circumstance).  This simply does a call directly to the sorl function to generate the thumbnail.

**In myapp/admin.py**

```
from myapp import models
from sorl.thumbnail import default
ADMIN_THUMBS_SIZE = '60x60'

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = models.MyModel
    list_display = ['my_image_thumb', 'my_other_field1', 'my_other_field2', ]

    def my_image_thumb(self, obj):
        if obj.image:
            thumb = default.backend.get_thumbnail(obj.image.file, ADMIN_THUMBS_SIZE)
            return u'<img width="%s" src="%s" />' % (thumb.width, thumb.url)
        else:
            return "No Image" 
    my_image_thumb.short_description = 'My Thumbnail'
    my_image_thumb.allow_tags = True
```

I based this off of the following question but added the sorl functionality.

[Django admin and showing thumbnail images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385094/django-admin-and-showing-thumbnail-images)