# Django: Uploaded Files Work Perfect ... Except in Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a Django model for a shirt.  Here's the relevant part:

```
class Shirt(models.Model):
    front_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="shirt_fronts")

class ShirtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

It works well in general; I can create new shirts in the admin, and upload pictures for them.  I can then view those shirts in my shirt view, and they show up fine.

The only problem is in the admin itself.  After I upload the image the image itself doesn't appear, only a link with the path to the image (eg. `shirt_fronts/someImage.jpg`).  If I then click the link I get taken to the wrong path for the image which (unsurprisingly) doesn't work.

So my question is, how do I fix that?  Specifically, how can I get the link to go to the right place or (better yet) get that link to be the image or a thumbnail version of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got the image working with code from here:    http://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/06/20/django-simple-admin-imagefield-thumbnail/

I created an `admin_image_widget.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class AdminImageWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = []
        if value and getattr(value, "url", None):
            image_url = '/media/dynamic/' + value.url
            file_name=str(value)
            output.append(u' <a href="%s" target="_blank"><img src="%s" alt="%s" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"/></a> %s ' % \
                (image_url, image_url, file_name, _('Change:')))
        output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))
        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

(NOTE: I modified the image URL and image tag.  The image URL I could probably do better by using the static file code instead of hard-coding the path.  The image tag I tweaked to limit the size of the thumbnail.)

I then moved my shirt admin class in to admin.py and made it:

```
class ShirtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'front_image':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = AdminImageWidget
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(ShirtAdmin,self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Shirt, ShirtAdmin)
```

Together this got me in-admin thumbnails!  Thanks Psychic Origami blog for the code snippet, and thanks Bigcortex for getting me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't show the thumbail by defaut. There has been several answers on how to show an upload image in the django admin.

[This should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174440/django-admin-how-to-display-thumbnail-instead-of-path-to-file)

As for the broken links, django doesn't serve media files out of the box. You can however configure it to serve them in debug mode.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[For more information on how to serve static files in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but I am already serving static media; as I said in my question, the images show up just fine on my site, it's only in the admin that they're not working.  As for the question you linked to, I tried adding the `def image_thumb` method from the answer to my model, but it doesn't appear to have done anything :(